# Oxford dictionary API call from angular app?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a personal dictionary using oxford dictionary API:https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation

I made a proxy.conf.json file to implement the API call,here is the code:

```
{
    "/oxfordapi": {
      "target": "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "app_id": "933daf11",
        "app_key": "34bef88a5c41a2d98f35d8783c887ec0"
      },
      "pathRewrite": {"^/oxfordapi" : ""}
    }
  }
```

Now i am trying to call it from my component file by using the service:

```
component.ts:

    ngOnInit() {

               this.gotHttpService.getDictonaryData().subscribe(
                  data => {

                    this.dictData = data;
                    console.log(this.dictData);

                  } ,
                  error => {
                    console.log("some error occured");
                    console.log(error.errorMessage);
                  }
                );



      }
```

Here is the service.ts file:

```
export class GotHttpService {
  word: String = "aardvark";
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("BlogHttpService is called")
      }
      private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log("Handle error Http calls")
        console.log(err.message);
        return Observable.throw(err.message);
      }
              getDictonaryData(): any {
                let myResponse = this._http.get('/oxfordapi/' + this.word);
                return myResponse;

              }
}
```

component.html:

```
  <input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
```

But how to make api call by taking the word from the input ngmodel and pass it to   getDictonaryData() method to fetch the word related data.

Any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated.Also is this the only way to fetch oxford dictionary API data using angular?

Comment: If you want to pass it to `getDictionaryData`, then you need to add a parameter to that function

Comment: You should use Observables, debounce... see an example -not over Oxford dictiionary https://dzone.com/articles/angular-observables-and-promises-how-to-use-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (change)="getDictonaryData()"/>
```

component.ts:

```
getDictonaryData() {
// Do code to fetch from this.dictData
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the required solution with `steps` and `code`:

**Steps:**

1. your `[(ngModel)]="name"` will store the word in `this.name`
2. When you click on button `getData()` method will be called which
   sends `this.name` to service funciton
3. In your service take a name parameter and if name is present send
   that name `getDictonaryData(name?)`

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
<button (click)="getData()"> Get Data </button>
```

**Component:**

```
getData() {
    this.gotHttpService.getDictonaryData(this.name).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.dictData = data;
            console.log(this.dictData);
        } ,
        error => {
            console.log("some error occured");
            console.log(error.errorMessage);
        }
    );

}
```

**Service:**

```
export class GotHttpService {
    word: String = "aardvark";
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        console.log("BlogHttpService is called")
    }
    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log("Handle error Http calls")
        console.log(err.message);
        return Observable.throw(err.message);
    }
    getDictonaryData(name?): any {
        if(name){
            this.word = name
        }
    let myResponse = this._http.get('/oxfordapi/' + this.word);
    return myResponse;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (change)="getDictonaryData()"/>

//pass name parameter into your service function like below

component.ts:
    name:string;
    ngOnInit() {

               this.gotHttpService.getDictonaryData(this.name).subscribe(
                  data => {

                    this.dictData = data;
                    console.log(this.dictData);

                  } ,
                  error => {
                    console.log("some error occured");
                    console.log(error.errorMessage);
                  }
                );



      }
//pass parameter in your service function also like below 

export class GotHttpService {
  word: String = "aardvark";
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("BlogHttpService is called")
      }
      private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log("Handle error Http calls")
        console.log(err.message);
        return Observable.throw(err.message);
      }
              getDictonaryData(word:any): any {
                let myResponse = this._http.get('/oxfordapi/' + word);
                return myResponse;

              }
}
```